# Getting react-router to work with Rails 5 & gem 'react-rails', '1.10.0'

Tags: javascript, ruby, reactjs, react-router, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 app with react installed with `gem 'react-rails', '1.10.0'`

I also want to use `react-router` so I manually have the react-router JS loading as their was no gem available. I can submit `ReactRouter` in the console a to confirm `ReactRouter` loads.

I'm trying to get react-router to work but it is erring. Here is my basic setup:

**welcome.html.erb**

```
<div id="root"></div>
<%= react_component 'RouterTest' %>
```

**_router_test.jsx**

```
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var Router = ReactRouter;
var browserHistory = ReactRouter.browserHistory;

var RouterTest = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return ( <div> <h1>RouterTest!</h1> </div> )
  }
});

var routes = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={RouterTest}/>
    </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routes , document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is error in the console with:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).
printWarning @ react.self-fd40d62….js?body=1:1275
warning @ react.self-fd40d62….js?body=1:1299
createElement @ react.self-fd40d62….js?body=1:3085
(anonymous) @ _router_test.self-b3b194f….js?body=1:23
react.self-fd40d62….js?body=1:841 Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
    at invariant (react.self-fd40d62….js?body=1:841)
    at Object._renderNewRootComponent (react.self-fd40d62….js?body=1:20670)
    at Object._renderSubtreeIntoContainer (react.self-fd40d62….js?body=1:20760)
    at Object.render (react.self-fd40d62….js?body=1:20781)
    at _router_test.self-b3b194f….js?body=1:29
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong getting React Router working? Thank you

Comment: I'm curious to know why will you want to use `router` with `react-rails` gem? I think your app will be routed by rails.

Comment: I need both. React router to make parts of the web app act like a single page app. In particular, a multi step sign up flow which I want in react router so there isn't a page refresh wit every step and I can transition nicely between the steps for UX.

Comment: Is this really required? I thought router was important when are doing a single page app and all pages need to had a different route. The case you talk about do you want to use `/sign_up/*` for all steps? If you just keep the url same and use a HOC, to render based on a state.